# How to observe a JButton from a different class?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton, observer-pattern

So I have a class that extends a `JPanel` and within the constructor I add my `JButtons` and whatever else I need to add. I also have a `MainFrame` class that is the container (`JFrame`) and this class will take an argument from a class called `FrameSwitcher` (Controller) which will assess what buttons were clicked, and pass the information to the `MainFrame`

I'm having troubles doing this, I can't find a proper way to do this. I do also wish to maintain the JButtons private and non static.

JPanel example:

```
public class MainMenu() {

    private JButton btnSinglePlayer, btnMultiPlayer;

    public MainMenu() {
        setLayout(null);

        btnSinglePlayer = new JButton("singlePlayer");
        btnSinglePlayer.setBounds(320, 25, 275, 130);
        add(btnSinglePlayer);

        btnMultiPlayer = new JButton("MultiPlayer");
        btnMultiPlayer.setBounds(320, 170 , 275, 130);
        add(btnMultiPlayer);

   }
}
```

FrameSwitcher:

```
public class FrameSwitcher implements panelListener { // panelListener is an interface defined else where.

    public FrameSwitcher(MainFrame frame) {
        // This is irrelevant to the question. 
    } 

    @Override
    public void gamePanel() {
        System.out.println("GamePanel Event: Recieved");
    }
    @Override
    public void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("mainMenu Event: Recieved");
    }
    @Override
    public void scoreBoardPanel() {
        System.out.println("scoreBoardPanel Event: Recieved");
    }
}
```

Then my MainFrame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private PanelListener panelListener;
    private JFrame mainContainer = new JFrame("Game");
    private JPanel mainMenu = new MainMenu();

    public void start() {
         mainContainer(mainMenu);
    }

    public MainFrame(JPanel frame) {
        mainContainer.getContentPane().add(frame);
        mainContainer.pack();
        // Other methods to initialize the frame
        return mainContainer;
     }

    public void switchFrames(PanelListener panelListener) {
        this.panelListener = panelListener; // PanelListener is an interface.
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton source = (JButton)e.getsource();

        if(source == MainMenu.btnSinglePlayer) {
            if(panelListener != null) {
                System.out.println("Recieved the event approriately.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, it does compile, but doesn't do what it is supposed to. Another thing is I currently have the JButtons as public and static, I don't want that.

Comment: `actionPerformed` is a method of the `ActionListener` interface, which your `MainFrame` class does not currently implement..so, what'd you expect? This entire design is screwy. Back to the basics.

Comment: Implement ActionListener in your FrameSwitcher class and, in your MainMenu class, add to each button an ActionListener(FrameSwitcher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MainMenu` class, you need to add some kind of listener that interested parties can register with, so when some event occurs, they can be notified.

The simplest solution would be to provide a `addActionListener` method which delegated to each of the buttons.  This, however, has may expose portions of the application you don't exposed (a listener now has direct access to the `JButton` and can do all kinds of nasty things to it).

A better solution would be to create something like a `MainMenuListener` which had methods like `startSinglePlayer` and `startMultiPlayer`

You would then provide a `add/removeMainMenuListener` method within in your `MainMenu` class.

Each button would then register there own `actionListener` and fire the appropriate menu listener event

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.EventListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainMenu extends JPanel {

    private JButton btnSinglePlayer, btnMultiPlayer;

    public MainMenu() {
        setLayout(null);

        btnSinglePlayer = new JButton("singlePlayer");
        btnSinglePlayer.setBounds(320, 25, 275, 130);
        add(btnSinglePlayer);
        btnSinglePlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireStartSinglePlayer();
            }
        });

        btnMultiPlayer = new JButton("MultiPlayer");
        btnMultiPlayer.setBounds(320, 170, 275, 130);
        add(btnMultiPlayer);
        btnMultiPlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireStartMultiPlayer();
            }
        });

    }

    public void addMainMenuListener(MainMenuListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(MainMenuListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeMainMenuListener(MainMenuListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(MainMenuListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void fireStartSinglePlayer() {
        MainMenuListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(MainMenuListener.class);
        if (listeners != null && listeners.length > 0) {
            for (MainMenuListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.startSinglePlayer();
            }
        }
    }

    public void fireStartMultiPlayer() {
        MainMenuListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(MainMenuListener.class);
        if (listeners != null && listeners.length > 0) {
            for (MainMenuListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.startMultiPlayer();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface MainMenuListener extends EventListener {

        public void startSinglePlayer();
        public void startMultiPlayer();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an ActionListener like this

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Then call,

```
yourButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

Comment: Wouldn't this force me to write my actionListeners in the actual MainMenu class? If not, how would it allow me to access the buttons from another class doing it this way? I assume MyActionListener would contain, in an array?, the JButtons and I pass them through the FrameSwitcher which returns the necessary data at MainFrame?

Comment: Your app is architected really strangely -- after a quick read, I can't really figure out what is talking to what, or what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you describe in simple terms what you want your finished app to do and I'll suggest a simplified design?

Comment: Sure, so this is simply the GUI for my application. It is meant to have a main menu that will have four buttons, singlePlayer, multiPlayer, scoreBoards and quit. Each button will initialize something different. Also, depending one what button is clicked, certain logic will come with it, so for example you click singleplayer then the single player logic will be called, and the game will continue on. Also, from within these panels, like single player, there will be a JMenu bar that will take you either to the main menu or scoreboards.